# OctoberCMS user.register event not firing?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I am listening to ***rainlab.user.register*** event but nothing seem to be happening. I want to fetch the registered user_id and do something with it e.g save it in another db.
I am using jwtauth plugin to register users. User can as well register via sociallogin plugin. I am testing user registration with postman, the registration request is successful but the event seem not be firing. How can I achieve this. This is my code inside the **boot() method** of my plugin.

```
Event::listen('eloquent.created:RainLab\User\Models\User', function($user) {

            $position= Position::where('title','staff')->first();
            $assign_position = new RankUser;
            $assign_position->user_id = $user->id;
            $assign_position->position_id= $position->id;
            $assign_position->save();

//Nothing being saved in DB after successful user registration.
```

});

I have also tried this:

```
Event::listen('rainlab.user.register', function($user) {

            $position = Position::where('title','staff')->first();
            $assign_position = new Position;
            $assign_position->user_id = $user->id;
            $assign_position->position_id= $position->id;
            $assign_position->save();       


});
```

But still nothing happens.

What May doing wrong. Some guidance please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some events are exclusive to plugins like

```
Event::listen('rainlab.user.register', function($user) { //code });
```

this `rainlab.user.registe` will fire only while you are `registering user` with `there controller only`

so if you `add user out of its scope this event will not fire`

As I suspect `jwtauth plugin` is `creating user by its own` using `RainLab\User\Models\User` model directly so this event will not fire.

however your `eloquent.created` event should be fired in this case but I find some problem in you `event string` as in code base

```
static::$dispatcher->{$method}("eloquent.{$event}: ".static::class, $this);
//there is one space, my guess is this is causing ^ you problem
```

so try to use `event string` with space like blow

```
Event::listen('eloquent.created: RainLab\User\Models\User', function($user) 
// try to add single space here ^ it should work
{ 
    //code 
});
```

if it didn't work please comment.

Comment: OK I will give a try and comment back. Thanks once again.